# function statement error in datastage server routine (BASIC). Very simple but didn't working

Tags: basic, datastage, routines

I have problem with using datastage server routine function statement.

Would you please notice me to what is problem with my code?

It is simple but I don't know why didn't work...

The code is

```
$INCLUDE DSINCLUDE JOBCONTROL.H
  FUNCTION GetTS(A,B)
  ARG1 = A:B
  RETURN(ARG1)

  DEFFUN GetTS(A,B)

  S='aaa'
  K='bbb'

  txt = GetTS(S,K)
  Ans = txt
```

And error message is

```
    Compiling: Source = 'DSU_BP/DSU.Test02', Object = 'DSU_BP.O/DSU.Test02'
************************************************?
Line 0002    
1 Errors detected, No Object Code Produced.
```

Normaly error message says what problem is, but this time is not...

Answer (score 1):

I Found Something. Server routins is one of Function statement.

So Function statement in Server Routine is impossible.